# Расширить google translate запрос для получения примеров?

Tags: google-translate

пытаюсь немного попользоваться "google translate api", как мы все знаем он с 2011 года не бесплатный. Но есть урл который работает. В этой статье. https://ctrlq.org/code/19909-google-translate-api

Так вот - этот урл возвращает очень маленький объект который содержит только одно слово.

```
https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=ru&dt=t&q=mother
```

Если мы глянем на запросы которые шлет google translate при переводе текста, то получим приблизительно вот такой урл. В котором местится намного больше информации, примеры и так д...

```
https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=en&tl=ru&hl=ru&dt=at&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=1&pc=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=2&tk=542002.924823&q=mother
```

Собственно вопрос.

1. Есть где-то информаци, где можно прочитать о клиентах, параметрах? Как подправить запрос так, чтоб пришли в ответе также примеры? Примеры ключей есть здесь, но они не очень подходят https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714426/what-is-the-meaning-of-google-translate-query-params
2. Или если рассмотреть вариант от Bing - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/, то немного непонятно как он считает символы. Он суммирует только символы которые есть в запросе?
3. Алтернатива?

Спасибо!